# Is there a way to have PC Automatically Turn On in Morning While Also Allowing Logmein Access?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access, logmein

I'm working for a business where the owners are away for a while. They use Logmein and would like to be able to turn the computer off at night and have it automatically turn on in the morning and have access to it via Logmein. I've got the computer turning on at 6am every morning via BIOS settings, but when the pc turns on, the Windows (Windows 10) login credentials seem to need to be entered by someone physically there with the pc before remote access via Logmein is possible.

Curious if there is any way around this so the owners could have access to the pc before anyone arrives for work in the morning? Any help or links to info would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a way to use a USB stick to log in to Windows? The idea being we could leave it inserted in the computer, then upon booting the USB stick could automatically log us in to Windows and then Logmein access would be granted without anyone needing to be physically at the computer?

Comment: Did you look at SysInternals autologon : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon ? This allows you to automatically log on a user.

Comment: @cdavid No, I didn't even know that existed, but I will definitely give it a shot. Thank you!